# Need help understanding a bash command

Tags: php, bash

It's actually a combination of php and bash:

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

I don't understand what `2>&1 & echo $!` is there for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2>&1` [redirects stderr to stdout](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), and `$!` ["Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command".](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html)

So, here's what happens:

1. You send both stderr and stdout of `$cmd` to a file named `$outputfile`.  If you didn't do `2>&1`, you wouldn't be able to read the stderr output in the file.
2. The following `&` means that process [runs in the background](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BGJOB).
3. Then you append the PID of `$cmd` (obtained through `$!`) to the end of `$pidfile`.

Comment: Yes it does: `$cmd` and `echo`